# ошибка “IndexError: list index out of range” в зависимости от условий в цикле while?

Tags: python

Не смог найти причину ошибки. Рабочий код:

```
linesplit=line.split(';')
Name_id=linesplit[0].split()  ## 'Анкета'
Name =linesplit[1].split() ## 'Имя'
ii=2
while ii <= len(linesplit) and linesplit[ii].strip() != '-' and linesplit[ii].strip()!='' :
    if linesplit[ii].strip()=='Телефон' :
        Phone =linesplit[ii+1].strip()
    ii=ii+1
```

Изменяю условие на `while ii <= len(linesplit) and linesplit[ii].strip() != '-':` или `while ii <= len(linesplit):` выдает ошибку

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: вы можете привести несколько примеров текста, который вы парсите?

Answer (score 1):

Все до банальности просто.
Функция len() выдает количество элементов в списке, а не максимальный индекс.

```
len([1,2,3,4]) # функция возвращает 4, так как в списке четыре элемента
```

Исправте ваш код на:

```
while ii < len(linesplit)
```

Python-way будет вот так вообще:

```
linesplit = line.split(';')
name_id = linesplit[0].split()  # Анкета
name =linesplit[1].split()  # Имя
for ii in range(2, len(linesplit))
    if linesplit[ii].strip() != '-' and linesplit[ii].strip()!='':
        if linesplit[ii].strip()=='Телефон' :
            Phone =linesplit[ii+1].strip()
```

Comment: Ещё -1 должно быть, т.к. в цикле идёт обращение к элементу с индексом ii+1

Answer (score 0):

Индексная арифметика, это все не python-way.

```
tokens = (l.strip() for l in line.split(';')) # чистим сразу все
name_id, name, *other = tokens
for line, nextline in zip(other, other[1:]): # создаем пары
    if line and line != '-':
        if line == 'Телефон':
            Phone = nextline
```

Условия сохранил, возможно они будут нужны топикстартеру в дальнейшем коде, но в данном фрагменте они избыточны. Достаточно только if line == 'Телефон'